# Is there an animation stack exchange site I can view?

Tags: support

I've been struggling with animation but I can't find an animation site on stack exchange. Is there not an animation site here? If there is where can I find it? If there isn't then where should I ask animation questions?

Keep in mind I'm using multiple software, so I'm not sure about asking in the Blender site.

Edit: Also I'm looking for animation in general. I.E. Games, pixel art, 2D, etc.

Comment: Could you clarify by "animation"? Is it 2D animation? 3D animation? General animation? Is it related to animation technique? Creating animation? Using software for animation?

Comment: @AndrewT. Animation in general. Specifically creating animations.

Answer (score 5):

The complete list of StackExchange sites is [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic).

If your question about animation is in the context of making a game, here is a fine enough place. If it's about creating 3D animated films, or the like, the Blender SE is probably your best bet. There is no dedicated "3D animation" SE site at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

Other options include:

- [Graphics Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation) that has a tag for animations;
- [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation) which also covers animation.

As noted in the comments, you'll want to specify a bit more what kind of help you seek and post to the most appropriate site.

Finally, as [Josh said in his answer](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2767/40264), there is no dedicated "3D animation" SE site at the moment.

Comment: This proposal seems to have been removed